# Understanding recursion better

Tags: c++, recursion

In attempt to understand recursion better, I tried to print some output within my code so that I could study the steps.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "print.h"
std::tuple<int, int, int> find_max_crossing_subarray(int A[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int max_left, max_right;
    int left_sum = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int sum = 0; 
    for(int i = mid; i >= low; i--) {
    sum += A[i];
    if(sum > left_sum) {
        left_sum = sum;
        max_left = i;
        }
    }
    int right_sum = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    sum = 0;
    for(int j = mid + 1; j <= high; j++) {
    sum += A[j];
    if(sum > right_sum) {
        right_sum = sum;
        max_right = j;
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(max_left, max_right, left_sum + right_sum);
}
std::tuple<int, int, int> find_max_subarray(int A[], int low, int high)
{
    if(high == low) {
        return std::make_tuple(low, high, A[low]);
    }
    else {
        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        std::tuple<int, int, int> left(find_max_subarray(A, low, mid));
        std::cout << "left: ";
        print(left);
        int left_low, left_high, left_sum;
        std::tie(left_low, left_high, left_sum) = left;
        std::tuple<int, int, int> right(find_max_subarray(A, mid + 1, high));
        std::cout << "right: ";
        print(right);
        int right_low, right_high, right_sum;
        std::tie(right_low, right_high, right_sum) = right;
        std::tuple<int, int, int> cross(find_max_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid, high));
        std::cout << "cross: ";
        print(cross);
        int cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum;
        std::tie(cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum) = cross;
        if(left_sum >= right_sum && left_sum >= cross_sum) {
            return left;
        }
        else if(right_sum >= left_sum && right_sum >= cross_sum) {
            return right;
        }
        else {
            return cross;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr_3[3] = {-3, 2, 3};
    int arr_4[4] = {5, -23, 1, 44};
    int arr_6[6] = {5, -23, 1, 44, -2, 5};
    int arr[16] = {-23, 3, 9 ,7, -12, 87, -25, 2, 3, 5, 32, -8, 6, -82, 3, 9};
    print(arr_4, 4);
    std::tuple<int, int, int> maple(find_max_subarray(arr_4, 0, 3));
    print(maple);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT::

```
5 -23 1 44 
left: 0 0 5
right: 1 1 -23
cross: 0 1 -18
left: 0 0 5
left: 2 2 1
right: 3 3 44
cross: 2 3 45
right: 2 3 45
cross: 0 3 27
2 3 45
```

I understand the first three lines of the output (that is, where the left, right, cross begin). But I do not understand where the fourth line and beyond come from. I tried tracing back the functions and I keep thinking I should get `left: 1 1 -23` in my fourth line of output after `cross: 0 1 -18`.

EDIT:

I should point out that after `left: 2 2 1`, although it's hard to visualize, I understand somewhat. The recursion has reached the end and the code is just cascading backwards.

SECOND EDIT:

I guess what is happening in the fourth line is that the very first `find_max_subarray` is completing and it is returning the first `if` statement in the function code. Now it is moving to the second `find_max_subarray`.

THIRD EDIT:

I guess my confusion is that the code doesn't cascade backwards but instead just returns to the very first call after it reaches the end of the recursion.

FOURTH EDIT:

When I go out to six elements though it seems like it doesn't simply return to the first call.

```
5 -23 1 44 -2 5 
left: 0 0 5
right: 1 1 -23
cross: 0 1 -18
left: 0 0 5
right: 2 2 1
cross: 0 2 -17
left: 0 0 5
left: 3 3 44
right: 4 4 -2
cross: 3 4 42
left: 3 3 44
right: 5 5 5
cross: 3 5 47
right: 3 5 47
cross: 2 5 48
2 5 48
```

I mean I guess it's because the sub array has three elements as opposed to two. So there are two pairs as opposed to one. It makes sense when you take it for granted but can't see it visually.

LAST EDIT:

So when I go out to 8, it goes in pairs. First two elements and then return the original call. The next two pairs and return the call. I'm not exactly sure why though in the odd case it won't return the call until both the first and second and first and third pairs have completed.

```
5 -23 1 44 -2 5 6 -3 
left: 0 0 5
right: 1 1 -23
cross: 0 1 -18
left: 0 0 5
left: 2 2 1
right: 3 3 44
cross: 2 3 45
right: 2 3 45
cross: 0 3 27
left: 2 3 45
left: 4 4 -2
right: 5 5 5
cross: 4 5 3
left: 5 5 5
left: 6 6 6
right: 7 7 -3
cross: 6 7 3
right: 6 6 6
cross: 5 6 11
right: 5 6 11
cross: 2 6 54
2 6 54
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:

The problem I was having in understanding the recursion is that for each recursive step I was using the original `high` value. I actually wrote it down on paper in blocks using the correct `high` and everything came together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding recursion better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838287/understanding-recursion-better).

Comment: Attaching a debugger and stepping through the code will help immensely.

Comment: How do I attach a debugger?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth. Your link points to this question.

Comment: @Comrade, are you using an IDE to write your code?  If so there should be debugging options visible somewhere...

Comment: There's gdb (GNU debugger) and there's also the debugger as part of Visual Studio (windows).

Comment: @CountMurphy. I'm using Mac OS X terminal.

Comment: @CountMurphy. I'm editing using vim and then compiling with clang++.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have to admit that got me :D I clicked it and was like... wtf happened here? :D

Comment: To my shame I've never attached to a debugger through the terminal.  This looks like it might give you what you need, though IMO using a C++ IDE will be easier.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7KALRhaHJA

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, that was awesome!

Comment: and i would start with a simpler algorithm for understanding recursion; fibonAacci, factorial,.... less moving parts to keep track of

Comment: @Comrade Oli has pulled a classic prank like this https://www.google.co.in/?#q=recursion

Comment: I wanted to understand recursion, so I decided to understand recursion.

Comment: @Comrade Get yourself [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) or eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above in my problem solved section following the last edit, I realized that in my analysis I was using the wrong value for `high`. I was not seeing this because although I was using blocks I was going in blocks of sequences and not blocks of blocks.

I went block by block with the updated `high` for each sub-block. I posted the illustration below. And this agrees with the output I was getting. The `return` statement accompanies each block.

Four element case:

```
(0,3)
    (0,1)
        (0,0) -> left
        (1,1) -> right
              -> cross
        return left
    (2,3)
        (2,2) -> left
        (3,3) -> right
              -> cross
        return right
        return cross
```

Five element case:

```
(0,4)
    (0,2)
        (0,1)
            (0,0) -> left
            (1,1) -> right
                  -> cross
            return left
        (2,2) -> right
              -> cross
        return left
    (3,4)
        (3,3) -> left
        (4,4) -> right
              -> cross
        return right
        return cross
```